# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'T' because 'T' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, uwp

```
 public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> All(string url)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> Collection=new ObservableCollection<T>();
        try
        {
            var response = await httpclient.GetResponseAsync(url);

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            {
                var content  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);

                foreach(var item in content)
                {
                    Collection.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException )
        {               
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException )
        {
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
        }

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return Collection;

    }
```

How way to loop one by one of content to Collection as my code.

1. I want to write once code and It is using many time in my project

Ex: ObservableCollection**"< Action >"** getListAll=t.All(".....");

CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'T' because 'T' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Can you post the section of code that's actually throwing the error?

i.e. the code at `ObservableCollection getListAll=t.All(".....");`

Comment: This code won't compile. You have to specify the generic type parameter in the method signature, not only in the return value type.

Comment: maybe `T` is defined at class level. @dymanoid but yes. you have to specify that `T` implements IEnumerable<something>

Comment: @Dillanm foreach(var item in content) error is showed here

Comment: @ M yes, I want to defined T is class

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary We expect a [mcve] in the question. If the provided example doesn't compile "as is", then this example isn't **complete**. We have to figure out all those things as this one (where is T defined? are there any constrains on T? and so on). That's the point.

Comment: What type would you expect `item` to be? If you know what it should be you can use `where T : IEnumerable<ItemType>` and it should work.

Comment: T will defined a class as Action or Account

Comment: public class BaseBussiness<T> : IBaseBussiness<T>

Comment: But what is the type of `item` in the foreach-loop?

Comment: Object of class
Account item in Content

Comment: Then make `T` an `IEnumerable<Account>` by adding a constraint.

Comment: but I don't know that I will pass any class before.

Comment: So I want to set default of object to I can set any class in a All(...)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this method will not compile you have to add  after method anem (All). Secondly if you are sure that response will be collection of T you have to deserialize to IEnumerable , then you will be able to use foreach on it.

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> All(string url)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> Collection=new ObservableCollection<T>();
        try
        {
            var response = await httpclient.GetResponseAsync(url);

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            {
                var content  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(response);

                foreach(var item in content)
                {
                    Collection.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException )
        {               
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException )
        {
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
        }

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return Collection;

    }
```

Comment: I want to defined T is class

Answer (score 0):

To make it compile you only need to change your method signature to:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> All(string url) where T:IEnumerable<T> {...}
```

I suspect that you are also not serializing properly, but can't be sure without underlying code. Consider using a wrapper class or check out [The documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).